# Conway's game of life: How to initialize the grid?

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to write a function `nextGen` that takes a single argument (the current grid) and then computes but doesn't print the new grid. Basically, I'm not sure how to do the checking bit, where it checks the 9 surrounding cells. First, I thought I could create a base grid made completely of 0's that is 2 rows and 2 columns larger than the current grid so that it would be a border of 0's, but I can't figure out how to get the initial grid's values into the base grid. My current code is:

```
def initlist(positions,initval):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(0,positions):
        newlist.append(initval)
    return newlist

def init2DTableV3(rows,cols,initval):
    newrow = initlist(cols,initval)
    table = initlist(rows,newrow)
    return table

def nextGen(current_grid):
    rows = len(current_grid)
    cols = len(current_grid[0])
    base_value = 0
    base_grid = init2DTableV3(rows + 2, cols + 2, base_value)
    import copy
    init_newgrid = copy.deepcopy(current_grid)
```

Could anyone help me out? I'm a beginner at Python so if someone could explain how to make `nextGen` using basic Python functions that would be great.

Comment: If you GoL grid is double wrapped around, then you have to check the neighbors across the grid.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have the base grid and you're not sure how to pad it with zeros on the edges, correct?

Sometimes it's easier to think about the problem in 1D first, and then see if it's possible to extend it to 2D. Let's say your 1D grid looks like

```
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
```

Then if you wanted to *pad* the array with a zero on each end, it would instead look like

```
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

This is pretty easy to do assuming you are just using standard Python lists. You can simply use [`list.insert()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) to insert in the beginning, and `.insert()` or `.append()` to insert at the end.

```
>>> L = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> L.insert(0,0)
>>> L.append(0)
>>> L
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

So let's try the same thing with a 2D list to see what happens:

```
>>> M = [[1,1],[1,1]]
>>> M.insert(0,[0,0])
>>> M.append([0,0])
>>> M
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]]
```

So, this gives a row on top and bottom with zeros, but we don't have the left and right side. We'll deal with that in a second. When I added the top and bottom row, I explicitly gave it the number of zeros needed (i.e. `[0,0]`). But you can easily do this automatically just using the length of a row:

```
>>> M = [[1,1],[1,1]]
>>> M.insert(0,[0]*len(M[0]))
>>> M.append([0]*len(M[0]))
>>> M
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]]
```

Now, each of the row vectors is only length 2, but it should be 4. An easy and explicit way to do this is just to loop through the sublists and insert and append the 0:

```
>>> for r in M:
...     r.insert(0,0)
...     r.append(0)
... 
>>> M
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This will give you your padded 2D list.

---

In general however, I would suggest using `numpy` for these tasks, as you can simply use [`numpy.pad()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) on a 2D `numpy` array for starters, but more complicated operations will also be faster and the arrays are easier to index, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use what is already present rather than add extra elements.

I recently wrote a copy of *Life* in javascript, but the ideas are the same. Each cell was identified by its coordinates and is initialized with an object (Python: dictionary) of its neighbors' coordinates.

```
makeCell(x, y) {
    let div = $('<div></div>');
    let id = "x" + x + "y" + y;

    let neighbors = this.getNeighbors(x, y);

    let attributes = {
                "id": id,
                "data-entity": _entity.id
        }

    $("#grid").append(div);
}

function getNeighbors(x, y) {
    let leftX =     x - 1;
    let rightX =    x + 1;
    let topY =      y - 1;
    let bottomY =   y + 1;

    // neighbor positions
    let neighbors = [
        "#x" + leftX + "y" + topY,
        "#x" + x + "y" + topY,
        "#x" + rightX + "y" + topY,
        "#x" + leftX + "y" + y,
        "#x" + rightX + "y" + y,
        "#x" + leftX + "y" + bottomY,
        "#x" + x + "y" + bottomY,
        "#x" + rightX + "y" + bottomY,
    ];
    return neighbors;
}
```

At the end of the round, all the living cells were stored in a list. Each living cell and each of its neighbors were checked to count its respective living neighbor cell.

```
this.cellCountNeighbors = function() {
    let count = 0;
    let neighbors = this.neighbors;
    let n = this.entity;
    let u = this;

    neighbors.forEach(function(neighbor) {
        let div = $(neighbor);
        if ($(div).hasClass("alive")) {
            count++;
        } else if (!check_cells.includes(neighbor)) {
            check_cells.push(neighbor);
        }
    });

    return count;
}
```

and the check condition for life:

```
this.setNextLife = function(_count) {
    if (this.alive) {

        if (_count == 2 || _count == 3) {
            return this.age++;
        } else {
            changes.push(this);
            return;
        }

    } else {
        changes.push(this);
    }
}
```

Where `changes` is a list of cells to be toggled `bool` alive/dead.